# What constitutes a "multiple-process site"?

Tags: asp.net

We have an ASP.Net web application which displays a chart using the .Net 3.5 Chart control and we are using the ChartHttpHandler to handle charting requests. The documentation for the ChartHttpHandler states:

> memory: Store the rendered chart images in the memory space of the
>   running process. Do not use this option in a server cluster or a
>   multiple-process site.

What constitutes a "multiple-process site"? How would I know if the target web server will be such a beast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-process is referring to what IIS6 introduced as a Web Garden (whereas a cluster would be a Web Farm). This can be observed on MSDN's page describing modifying the worker process of a web farm: [Performance Application Pool Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720391%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

As far as detecting, if you go to the AppPool's properties and look for the number of worker processes, this will tell you if you're running multi-process or not.

For example, IIs 7.5's settings can be found on the advanced properties of the AppPool:

[image: AppPool settings of IIS 7.5]

As a follow-up, here's another article (from MSDN) describing how to [configure web gardens in IIS6](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/659f2e2c-a58b-4770-833b-df96cabe569e.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some context as to *why* this is required, it seems that `ChartHttpHandler` relies heavily on Session state, and and statics, like a [static constructor](http://support2.dundas.com/forum/printable.aspx?m=15898) to retain state. This will require that subsequent client requests from the same client return to the same process for successful continuation of state of the chart (e.g. I believe the `img` tags rendered by the control html need to return to the same server to render the image)

However, it does appear that there is a [workaround](http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1054) for Web Farms and Gardens involving using a common shared file system file cache, as well as using [out of process Session state modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586(v=vs.140).aspx) such as State Server or Sql Session State.

Comment: We've never successfully managed to get this application to work with out of state session modes (don't ask!) so we are stuck with a single web-server offering. I guess we will have to make that a single process web server now, or not use the ChartHttpHandler at all.. Thanks to both.